# Worldserver upgrade on SDL Tridion 8.5 CMS

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, worldserver

I was going through the documentation for implementing WorldServer in SDL Tridion 8.5. As per documentation, in order to upgrade WorldServer  10 to WorldServer 11. Currently, the details of WS is configured on TranslationManager.xml file. As per documentation, I tried to point to the new WS URL on TranslationManager.xml but I don't see a Translate option on CMS. Could you share if there is any documentation on what needs to change on WS 11 & SDL CMS, please? 
Also, apart from updating details on TranslationManager.xml  is there anything else to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you've got a configuration problem, or if you're just not sure where to go next to continue the setup. One thing I'll point out is that if you're upgrading from WS 10 to 11, the API endpoint has changed ([per the documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-595ADA78-8D59-49DC-BFD7-8D219620A3A9#docid=GUID-C493D2B7-7B4F-484F-A536-8CD78C6041BE&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C493D2B7-7B4F-484F-A536-8CD78C6041BE)).

Previously for WS 10, the endpoint was structured like:

```
<WorldServer username="admin" password="wsadmin">http://ws.dev:8080/ws/services</WorldServer>
```

however it's changed for WS 11:

```
<WorldServer username="admin" password="wsadmin">http://ws.dev:8080</WorldServer>
```

That one's gotten me before. If you're just wondering how you can test out if the connection is working, you can try opening a publication and going to the translation tab or just clicking on the hamburger menu in the CME and try loading the Translations page. You should see errors if the connection to WorldServer isn't successful in my experience.

Once you have the connection working, you'll just need to configure your source and target items for sending content for translation and you should be able to test out sending items. There are a number of other things you can configure though: polling of WorldServer, email notifications for jobs sent out, how jobs and job items are chunked up on the translation side and because you're on WS 11 you can also setup retrieving items for preview in the CME of an in-translation item.

I'd recommend checking out these sections of the documentation:

- [Configuration Translation Manager](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-595ADA78-8D59-49DC-BFD7-8D219620A3A9#docid=GUID-FD448569-E7C4-4FFC-80E6-3B388F5EFC35&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FD448569-E7C4-4FFC-80E6-3B388F5EFC35)
- [Configuration of source and target items](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-595ADA78-8D59-49DC-BFD7-8D219620A3A9#docid=GUID-A6163D2F-362B-404E-8F68-5A8F8D4E708C&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A6163D2F-362B-404E-8F68-5A8F8D4E708C) (publication, folder, sg or category)
- [Controlling what content gets sent for translation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-595ADA78-8D59-49DC-BFD7-8D219620A3A9#docid=GUID-8722AF3C-696F-4909-9A0F-198235EC2EAB&filename=GUID-9626D6F9-477B-4639-9B5E-8E5FD4FCA4D5.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8722AF3C-696F-4909-9A0F-198235EC2EAB)

Comment: Hi, @Josh Hebb thanks for the details. After changing the <worldserver> config, I'm unable to configure source/target for publications on CME. I'm getting an error : "Unable to load translation configuration". Not sure if there is anything else needs to be configured. I restarted TMS & CM service host as per the documentation. But no luck! :(

Comment: I think the next step will be to check the logs @ragmn. If you open the TranslationManager.xml config file, the location of the log is under the LogFolder node. If you go to that folder, you can open the latest TM log file and let us know what error you're seeing.